# Best datatype for returning bulk data from a C++ function

Tags: c++, function, types, complex-data-types

I have one C++ method/function like below

```
std::string TestWrapImpl::doProcess(std::string dirPath, std::string cmdLine) {
  std::string TestWrapVar = "";

  // Businesslogic here
  // TestWrapVar = {BulkData From Business Logic} 
  // Sample Bulk Data - "<xml><node01><FNAME>KRISHNA</FNAME></node01>
  //                     <node02><FNAME>KRISHNA</FNAME></node02></xml>"

  return TestWrapVar;
}
```

What is the best datatype to return this 2GB of XML Content? (Maybe a string datatype can't hold a 2GB string.)

Comment: What platform? How much memory? The most obvious answer would be to write it to a file and return the path to the file.

Comment: Currently I'm Working in Linux & G++. Memory available is 5GB. Issue here is Currently making my function as "request per response model" for different account holders. if i write into file, obviously i need to maintain accountholder id + uniqueid as filename prefix. Secondly daily i have 200 - 1000 hits on my app. So 200*2GB = {out of my size in linux box.}

Comment: The caller could delete the file after it was written. And the file can be stored in memory (`tmpfs` for example) or on disk. You can limit the number of such files you permit at once. But I think you're issue has nothing to do with the datatype for returning the data but more with how to manage and represent a large data set.

Comment: oh ! is their any way to do this, except file writing?

Comment: Would you prefer to keep it all in memory? If so, you can use a linked-list of fixed-sized blocks, say 32MB each.

Comment: You could implement some chunked storage like David suggests either as a `std::list<std::array<char, N>>` or as a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<char[]>>`, or even a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

Comment: @OpenSourceDev - If I was an account holder, I wouldn't want a 2 GB reply! You might want to implement a way for the user to limit the requests, or to show the reply one page at at time.

Answer (score 2):

Better write content into files and map them to the memory (I hope, you have a 64-bit environment).

Although, XML is one of most inappropriate formats to hold such amounts of data. It's due to large coefficient of increasing data size and low parsing speed.